# Are there any Star Wars vehicles that have not yet been produced in a Lego kit?

Tags: star-wars

This includes all six films and the Clone Wars spin-offs.  Every vehicle I can think seems to have been produced as part of a kit at some point.  Are there any that haven't?

Comment: Did you read [Wookiepedia](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Main_Page)? All of it?

Comment: But, all joke aside, LEGO is likely to focus on visual Star Wars rather than obscure expanded universe reference, so I can see why you restricted your question to the films and Clone Wars.

Comment: Actually, there are some sets that take place using expanded universe that LEGO did make, such as the sith sorceror/warrior ship from the old republic.

Comment: @CBredlow There's [quite a few](http://brickset.com/browse/themes/?theme=Star%20Wars&subtheme=Expanded%20Universe) more then that

Comment: EU sets seem to mostly be based on (Old Republic) video games

Comment: @bungeshea Ah I forgot about the Rogue Shadow! Need to buy that one. Given enough Lego, [anything in possible](http://www.fbtb.net/features/interview-erik-varszegi/).

Comment: Wikipedia has *[List of Lego Star Wars sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Lego_Star_Wars_sets)*.

Comment: CapnRex has started a series on what's missing, and an interesting take on why those sets might be missing over at BrickSet: http://brickset.com/news/category-What-s-Missing

Answer (score 20, accepted):

As far as I know, all of the most common vehicles have been produced, but I could be forgetting something. There are many obscure vehicles which have not been produced, but I don't see any reason to try to list them all. Some examples would be many of the pod racers from Episode I, many of the hundreds of vehicles shown on Coruscant, or several of the speeders seen in the Mos Eisley approach in Episode IV.

The most notable vehicle that I can think of that has not been produced to my knowledge are the Royal Cruisers from the prequels:

[image]

Update:

I had previously been mentioned the Nebulon-B Frigate featured in Episode V and VI:

[image: Nebulon-B movie shot]

The Nebulon-B has now been produced:

[image: Nebulon-B set]

Comment: Not that it hasn't been [made in LEGO by fans](http://mocpages.com/moc.php/175408) - and there's a (smaller) [one on Cuusoo](http://lego.cuusoo.com/ideas/view/16795) too. But seeing the fragility of the center section (seriously, who does design spaceships that way?), I'm not sure LEGO would be willing to make an official one. It's not so much swooshable as explodable.

Comment: There hasn't been too many of the rebel cruisers (i'm lumping all of the ships larger than a fighter together) made by LEGO.  THere's that one transportish ship they take from Hoth that wasn't used.

Comment: The podracers are an obvious one, I should have thought of that.

Comment: @Joubarc, depending on the scale you're building at, I can think of a half-dozen ways of reinforcing that center section.

Answer (score 9):

There are quite a few:

- The [Naboo silver cruisers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Star_Wars_spacecraft#Naboo_royal_cruiser) - I think there were three in all - none produced.
- Several [speeders](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speeder_bike) in *[Episode II](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Wars_Episode_II:_Attack_of_the_Clones)*, all seen in the city and several transporters too.
- The Jedi speeders, some have been made, but not in all the colours seen in the movies.

And as for the clone wars series, the list becomes lengthy...

Answer (score 9):

The ones from the original 6 movies and that should have been made:

- Naboo queen silver cruiser from episode 1 (with queen handmaid fig(s)!)
- Clone quadrans (if I'm naming them correctly) from episode 2 (the guns taking down a Trade Federation ship)
- Rebel transport shuttle from episode 5 (escaping Hoth) and 6
- Rebel medical frigate from episode 5 and 6
- Mon calamari cruiser

Very optional in my opinion:

- Trade Federation admiral ship
- Trade Federation transport ship
- Separatist cruiser from the opening scene of episode 3
- The two other Naboo cruisers
- A Uta Pau shuttle seen on two or three images (and natives from the planet in the set please!)
- A clone tank seen on two images on a bridge under snow in the order 66 scene

Not ships, but still should have been made:

- Gungan city (and, why not, one big creature carrying their shield generator and one of their catapults)
- A Jedi Temple?
- Kaminoans!
- Geonosis arena beasts
- One of the Skywalkers house?
- Republic Senate with Sidious and Yoda fighting
- Bizarre blue/purple creature on which clones are riding on Felucia (order 66 scene)
- Mustafar locals (humanoids and lava beasts seen on one image)
- Asteroid field locals sheltering Padme at the end of episode 3
- Bantos... Bantas... Ban... you know the big hairy thing the Tuskens are riding in episode 4

Answer (score 5):

Millions! Separatist War Ship,UT-AT, Republic Assault Ship, Umbara Military Canon, and many many ships from the Clone Wars TV show (From Arc's this season mostly)

Answer (score 3):

Banthas! That to me is the largest oversight in Lego's portrayal of the original movie so far.  This is made even more baffling with the upcoming release of a "Tatooine battle pack" that comes with yet another Tusken Raider...missed opportunity there!

Answer (score 3):

TPM: Trade Federation Battleship, Trade Federation Landing Ship, Naboo Royal Starship, Coruscant Air-Taxi

ATOC: H-Type Nubian Yacht

TCW: Trident Drill Assault Craft, Umbaran Starfighter

ROTS: Separatist Cruiser, The Invisible Hand

REBELS: Imperial Interdictor, Mining Guild TIE-Fighter

RO: AT-ACT, TIE Reaper, The Profundity, Hammerhead Corvette, Zeta-Class Imperial Shuttle

ANH: pretty fleshed out

TESB: GR-75 Medium Transport, Nebulon-B Frigate

ROTJ: Mon Calamari Star Cruiser

TFA: pretty fleshed out

TLJ: First Order Dreadnought, Canto-Bight Police Speeder, The Raddus, The Supremacy